# problem with regex not recognizing some special chars (german letters) in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to detect strings containing special characters like `ä, ü, ö and ß`

I have a list of allowed characters, and I am using it like this, to detect any string that contains anything else but these:

```
 grepl("[^0-9a-zA-Z$%^*&]","aaüh")
```

However, this returns FALSE. So it fails to detect the special `ü`.

How can I make explicit that only latin characters are allowed?

Comment: It returns `TRUE` for me. This might be dependent on what locale you're working in though. I.e. - `a-z` might capture `ü` in a German locale.

Comment: Relevant info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765610/when-does-locale-affect-rs-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the string first. I used the base R function `iconv` to encode the string. The `iconv` function will create `"aa<U+00FC>h"` in this example.

```
gimme <- function(val) {iconv(val, from = "UTF-8", "ASCII", "Unicode")}

grepl("[^0-9a-zA-Z$%^*&]", gimme("aaüh"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and still gives me FALSE...  Now I changed the locale and language as some other players suggested `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English");
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")` and it works without iconv.